# parallelize a resultSet

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i'm using spark with cassandra and i've executed this script :

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector

val cc = CassandraConnector(sc.getConf)
val select = s"SELECT channel, ctid, cvid , WRITETIME(source) FROM "+CASSANDRA_SCHEMA+"."+table+";"


val session = cc.openSession()
val results = session.execute(select)
```

PS: I'm oblige to use this method because of the `WRITETIME(source)`. 
But the `results` val is an resultSet and i wonder if it is possible to parallelize this resultSet in order to get an RDD

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This doesn't look like Java at all. Probably you're working with Scala.

Comment: Do you need it in a session? Could you just use a `CassandraSQLContext`?

Comment: Yes i have to use a session to get the `WRITETIME(source)`. This function is not available in Version 1.1 of cassandra spark connector.

Answer (score 1):

'results' is an instance of `ResultSet` and cannot be converted in an RDD directly.
First, you need to materialize the complete collection, by requesting `all` elements:

```
val collection = results.all
```

Still this won't help, as the result is a `java.util.List` and we need a Scala collection. a simple transform will help:

```
val sCollection = collection.asScala
```

Now, just simply parallelize it using the sparkContext parallelize method:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(sCollection)
```

From there, you can operate on the `Row` objects of this collection.

Comment: Yes thank you for your answer, but my problem is the `results.all` function return an `outOfMemory error`. Caused by the big number of rows.

Comment: Following DataStax JIRA, it's possible to access `WRITETIME` through the spark driver: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-8   You just need to upgrade to v1.2.0

Comment: Yes but i can't  upgrade to v1.2.0 because i'm using Spark Job Server too. And There no version Of spark Job Server Compatible with v1.2.0